# XCode not finding Firebase v2.1.2 (Framework not found error)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I've been using v1 of Firebase in an iOS project just fine for a little over 6 months now, so I know I've got everything set up correctly as far as dependencies and other linker flags go, but for some reason I cannot seem to simply update Firebase when I try and 1) remove the old Firebase framework from the project and then 2) drag and drop the new one in.  I get the old "Framework not found" error...

[image]

I know the search paths are fine because I'm putting it in the same exact directory as the old framework, and I can remove/replace the old framework ad nauseam and it builds just fine.  I've also made sure it appears in the "Link Binary With Libraries" just like the old version, so I'm not forgetting that.  The only valid architecture I have set is armv7.

What am I missing here?  Are there any extra steps involved with updating to v2?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up downloading the XCode templates, starting a new Single View Firebase project, and the dragging and dropping the same .framework folder from that template project into my actual project and it worked!